# How to delete an input stored in array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, input, splice

```
let input;
const todos = [];

while (input !== 'exit') {
    input = prompt('Type what you want to do');
    if (input === 'new') {
        input = prompt("What's your todo?");
        todos.push(input);
    } else if (input === 'list') {
        console.log(`This is your list of todos: ${todos}`);
    } else if (input === 'delete') {
        input = prompt('Which todo would you like to delete?');
        if (todos.indexOf(input) !== -1) {
            todos.splice(1, 1, input);
            console.log(`You've deleted ${input}`);
        }
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

That's what I've tried so far.
I'm starting into programing and this is part of a small exercise that I have to ask from a prompt to add a new todo, list it all and then delete.
What i'm trying to do is: take that input stored at input variable and then check if its inside the array, if its positive I want to delete it and not from the index but from the word.

Like:

-delete
-eat
//check if its inside array
//if true delete it from

I apologize if its a dumb question. I tried online and couldn't find it.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO! That's not quite how splice works. Please check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice. The idea is to store the index of the element and use that to splice by index instead of hardcoding index 1 for the splice. The third parameter to splice is the optional data you want to add, not the data to remove (yes, it's a weird function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code fixed below:

```
input = prompt('Which todo would you like to delete?');
const index = todos.indexOf(input);
if (~index) {
  todos.splice(index, 1);
  console.log(`You've deleted ${input}`);
}
```

You can read more about [`Array.prototype.splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and the [bitwise operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_NOT) on the corresponding MDN docs.

Answer (score 2):

You could change the loop to a `do while` loop to check the exit instead of using `break` at last else of checking.

Then you need to store the result of `indexOf` and splice the item with the index.

```js
let input;
const todos = [];

do {
  input = prompt('Type what you want to do');
  if (input === 'new') {
    input = prompt("What's your todo?");
    todos.push(input);
  } else if (input === 'list') {
    console.log(`This is your list of todos: ${todos}`);
  } else if (input === 'delete') {
    input = prompt('Which todo would you like to delete?');
    const index = todos.indexOf(input)
    if (index !== -1) {
      todos.splice(index, 1);
      console.log(`You've deleted ${input}`);
    }
  }
} while (input !== 'exit');
```

A slifhtly better approach is to take a [`switch` statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).

```js
let input;
const todos = [];

do {
    input = prompt('Type what you want to do');
    switch (input) {
        case 'new':
            input = prompt("What's your todo?");
            todos.push(input);
            break;
        case 'list':
            console.log(`This is your list of todos: ${todos}`);
            break;
        case 'delete':
            input = prompt('Which todo would you like to delete?');
            const index = todos.indexOf(input)
            if (index !== -1) {
                todos.splice(index, 1);
                console.log(`You've deleted ${input}`);
            }
    }
} while (input !== 'exit');
```

Comment: I'll definitely improve it. 
Appreciate your time to help!

Answer (score 1):

Follow [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) for the correct usage of splice.

What you would want is something like this:

```
  todos.splice(yourIndex,1);
```

First param is the start index from where you want to manipulate the array and the second is the count. Splice is in place and will modify the array.

Answer (score 1):

Use indexOf method  to find the index and then use splice method !

```
let todos = ['one' , 'two', 'three'];
let index;

// Wrap the whole code in function to make it resusable
let user_input = prompt(" Enter your to-do to delete ");
index = todos.indexOf(user_input);

if (index !== -1) {
  todos = todos.splice(index ,1);
  console.log("Entered to-do deleted successfully");
} else {
  alert("Entered to-do doesn't exists");
}
```

Also remember  as a beginner it is good to have questions !

Comment: Appreciate your tip in this matter! Already checking at documentation to understand better and practice more. Thanks again!